# How to add dynamic variable name in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, scope

I am having two files,

**App.tsx:**

```
const data = {games:{type: [], sport: [], category: []}}
```

The above is the dynamic data I receive .

I am in the need to set the above keyof typeof data.games to the type valid like,

```
type Valid = keyof typeof data.games
```

If it is same file then no issues to assign like the above.

But I have type file separately like,

**Apptype.ts**

```
// How can I make the below keyof typeof [dynamicName] ?
export type Valid = keyof typeof data.games;

export interface IOption {
  id: number;
  value: string;
  valid: Record<Valid, number[]>;
}
```

In the above file `data.games` throw error because there will not be such variable name in this file.

So how can I assign the dynamic value to `keyof typeof [.....]`?

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit disable-dependent-dropdown-option-in-reactjs (forked)]

Comment: This just looks like a scoping issue. Either export `data` from where it's defined or define `Valid` in the same module and export that

Comment: @Phil, Thanks for your comment. Could you please add solution on the same as I am new to typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export and import the data from the `App.tsx`. And import types from `Apptype.ts` using

`App.tsx`:

```
import type { IOption, IState } from "./Apptype";
// ...
```

`Apptype.ts`

```
import { data } from "./App";

export interface IState {
  [key: string]: number;
}

export type Valid = keyof typeof data.games;

export interface IOption {
  id: number;
  value: string;
  valid: Record<Valid, number[]>;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-dependent-dropdown-option-in-reactjs-forked-hphzm0?file=/src/App.tsx:96-145)